# ng-click directive not passing desired parameter

Tags: angularjs, parameter-passing

I have the following piece of angular code: (it's a modal-popover menu which uses the following js library: http://scruffles.github.io/BootstrapModalPopover/).

```
<div ng-repeat="purchasedItem in purchased" class="row item_summary">
    <!-- edited for brevity -->
     <div id="{{purchasedItem.code}}-popover" data-product-id="{{purchasedItem.code}}" class="popover" style="display: none;">
       <div class="arrow"></div>
       <h3 class="popover-title" style="display: none;"></h3>
       <div class="popover-content">
         <div class='popover-menu-left'>
           <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click='purchasedItems.removePurchasedItem(purchasedItem)'>Verwijderen</button><br>
         </div>
         <div class='popover-menu-right-template'>
           <div class='number-content' style="display: none;">
            <div ng-controller="numpadCtrl as numpad" class="numpad">
                 <!-- edited for brevity -->
                 <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm" value="enter" data-item-id='{{purchasedItem.code}}' ng-click="numpad.flushNumber(purchasedItem.code)"></input>
            </div>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class='popover-menu-right-content'>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

the problem lies with this particular piece of code:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-sm" value="enter" data-item-id='{{purchasedItem.code}}' ng-click="numpad.flushNumber(purchasedItem.code)"></input>
```

The data-item-id attribute was added just to see if I could get retrieve the code - this works just fine! But when I set a breakpoint in the flushNumber function, the parameter passed is undefined.

The code for the numpad controller is the following (it doesn't really do anything yet)

```
sportOaseControllers.controller('numpadCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    var parent = this;

    parent.currentEntry = "";

    parent.addNumber = function (number) {
      parent.currentEntry = parent.currentEntry.concat(number);
      console.log(parent.currentEntry);
    };

    parent.cancel = function() {
      console.log('cancelled!');
      parent.currentEntry = "";
    };

    parent.flushNumber = function(code) {
      console.log('flushing!' + code);
    }
}]);
```

The only thing which might be a clue is that the $scope injected into the numpad controller is null - my knowledge of angular is too minimal to do any real debugging however. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: "But when I set a breakpoint in the flushNumber function, the parameter passed is undefined. " Can you explain or show us the code for this?

Comment: ofcourse, I edited the original post to include the code.

Comment: isn't the HTML in the numpadCtrl namespace? Why are you using `var parent = this` oh sorry I saw now

Comment: It might have something to do with the fact that you're creating a controller for each of the purchasedItems, since each `ng-repeat` iteration creates a new scope and you create another scope of your controller. So you have many `numpad` controllers. Do you need to create one for each, or can you scope it above the `ng-repeat` ?

Comment: The strange thing is when I place the ng-controller directive on the div enclosing the one with the ng-repeat in it, the controller doesn't get called at all...

Comment: Can you construct a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/wq52ucb4/2/), what AngularJS version do you have?
`controller as` was introduce since 1.2 it's not available before that.

HMTL:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="FirstCtrl">

    {{purchasedItem}}

    <div ng-controller="numpadCtrl as numpad" class="numpad">
        <!-- edited for brevity -->
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm" value="enter" data-item-id='{{purchasedItem.code}}' ng-click="numpad.flushNumber(purchasedItem.code)"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function FirstCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.purchasedItem = {
        code: 'hello'
    };
}

function numpadCtrl($scope) {
    this.flushNumber = function (code) {
        console.log(code);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, the angular version I am using is v1.3.16

Comment: I still need to take a look at it, I'll let you know if I have any new info =)